# Как сделать внешний подзапрос?

Tags: sql

```
(Select date_from,place_trip, count(*) from blank 
group by date_from,place_trip
having count (trip_grz) >1)
```

По данному запросу он бьет значения, но хотелось бы развернуть найденные совпадения для более детальной информации. Необходим внешний `select`.

Comment: Так в чём проблема? Если я правильно понял просто обозначаете ваш этот подзапрос какой-нибудь буквой и делаете из него `select`: `select z.place_trip,t.something from (select ...) z left join another_table t on ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select t. (Выбираем таблицы которые нужны)
From blank t
Where (t.date_from, t.place_trip) in
(Select d.date_from,d.place_trip
 from blank d
 group by d.date_from,d.place_trip
 having count (d.trip_grz) >1)
```

В итоге сам разобрался спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT subquery.*, blank.*
FROM blank 
JOIN ( SELECT date_from, place_trip, COUNT(*) AS cnt
       FROM blank 
       GROUP BY date_from, place_trip
       HAVING COUNT(trip_grz) > 1
       ) AS subquery USING (date_from, place_trip)
ORDER BY date_from, place_trip;
```